# ui-sref not working in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following angular code in header.html

```
           <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">                  
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                        
                    <li ng-if='loginState.loggedIn' class="dropdown">           
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle"                              
                            data-toggle="dropdown"                              
                            id="userDropdown"                                   
                            role="button"                                       
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">         
                            {{loginState.currentUser}} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>                                                    
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                            <li><a ui-sref="app.profile">Your Profile</a></li>  
                            <li><a ui-sref="app.settings">Settings</a></li>     
                        </ul>                                                   
                    </li>                                                       
                    <!-- this would work                                        
                    <li><a ui-sref="app.profile">Your Profile</a></li>          
                    -->                                                         
                </ul>                                                           
            </div>
```

The states code are very straightforward:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',                             
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {                              
    $stateProvider                                                              
    .state('app', {                                                             
        url: '/',                                                               
        views: {                                                                
            'header': {                                                         
                templateUrl: 'static/templates/header.html',                    
            },                                                                  
            'content': {                                                        
                templateUrl: 'static/templates/landing.html',                   
            },                                                                  
            'footer': {                                                         
                templateUrl: 'static/templates/footer.html',                    
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
    })                                                                          
    .state('app.profile', {                                                     
        url: 'profile',                                                         
        views: {                                                                
            'content@': {                                                       
                templateUrl : 'static/templates/profile.html',                  
                controller  : 'ProfileController'                               
           }                                                                    
        }                                                                       
    })                                                                          
    ;                                                                           

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');                                          
}])
```

So basically once logged in, I would have a dropdown from the top right corner, and I want to transit to other states when clicking entries in dropdown menu.

However, when clicking `Your Profile` nothing happens, the state has not gone to app.profile. If I move the `ui-sref` out of the dropdown and to the navbar directly(like the commented code), it works perfectly fine.

So is there something prevent `ui-sref` from working in a bootstrap dropdown?

Comment: Can you please try ng-show instead of ng-if on <li> element

Comment: it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it's the `data-toggle` attribute in the dropdown menu `ul`, once it's removed everything works fine.

I don't know why it would prevent `ui-sref` from working, thought it would just collapse the menu.

EDIT:

The problem is reproducible only if I load jquery after ui-router:

```
  <script src="//npmcdn.com/angular-ui-router@latest/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I swap the order it works fine.

Comment: probably, I created an issue on ui.router github repo, haven't got a reply yet.