# AngularJS ui-sref not working in navbar dropdown Bootstrap on mobile

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, angular-ui-router

Using UI-Router for Angular and Bootstrap for a navbar I'm trying to turn anchor inside dropdown clickable on but isn't working on mobile. I saw [ui-sref not working in bootstrap dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411857/ui-sref-not-working-in-bootstrap-dropdown) and the solution is not working for me. I'm not getting any error on console.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="mainnav-toggle is-open" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".mainnav-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>

    <nav class="mainnav-collapse collapse" role="navigation" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
      <ul class="mainnav-menu">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
            Links<i class="mainnav-caret"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

            <li>
              <a ui-sref="auth.add()">
              <i class="fa fa-users dropdown-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Link 1
              </a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a ui-sref="auth.list()">
              <i class="fa fa-history dropdown-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Link 2
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Reference Order:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery.slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/src/loading-bar.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-toggle/dist/angular-bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/app.min.js"></script>
```

JS: the UI-Router config:

```
var app = angular.module('accountsMod');
app.config(function routeConfig ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

$stateProvider
  .state('auth.add', {
        url: '/accounts/add',
        controller: 'AccountController',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/account/add.html'
    })
   .state('auth.list', {
        url: '/accounts/add',
        controller: 'AccountController',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/account/list.html'
    })
```

}

The problem focus is: when I touch on these anchors in navbar collapsed according to responsive design provided by bootstrap on mobile phone, then menu closes and nothing happening.

Comment: try changing `ui-sref="auth.add()"` to `ui-sref="auth.add"`. Do same for other one also.

Comment: I tried this solution with no success, I had replaced according you describes but it does still not working

Answer (score 0):

One solution: I had to install 'angular-ui-bootstrap' package and did some changes as follow:

1. Referencing to directive:
   `var app = angular.module('accountsMod',['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);`
2. Replacing each html tag for toggle menu as follow (about old in comment):

HTML:
`
    
      Toggle navigation

```
<nav class="mainnav-collapse collapse" role="navigation" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
  <ul class="mainnav-menu">
    <li uib-dropdown> <!--OLD: <li class="dropdown">-->
      <a uib-dropdown-toggle> <!--OLD:<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">-->
        Links<i class="mainnav-caret"></i>
      </a>
      <ul uib-dropdown-menu><!--OLD: <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">-->
        <li>
          <a ui-sref="auth.add()">
          <i class="fa fa-users dropdown-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Link 1
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a ui-sref="auth.list()">
          <i class="fa fa-history dropdown-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Link 2
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

`

So the `UI-SREF links` started working in mobile navigation!! Tks!